# Fetch data from API on setInterval without creating another HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

My code basically fetches API data, creates HTML elements for each and update the innerHTML elements with API data.

How can I possibly refresh the data from API and update it without creating another HTML elements?

This is my actual code:

```
let divCrypto = document.getElementById("divCrypto");
let temp, p1, p2, p3, imgz;

let data = [];
const getData = async () => {

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   coinName = await fetch("https://api.coinlore.net/api/tickers/")
    .then((res) => res.json());
  data.push(coinName.data[i]);
  p1 = document.createElement("p");
  p2 = document.createElement("p");
  p3 = document.createElement("p");
  p1.innerHTML = "Coin:" + " " + data[i].name;
  p2.innerHTML = "Coin:" + " " + data[i].price_usd;
  p3.innerHTML = data[i].percent_change_7d + "%";
  divCrypto.appendChild(p1);
  divCrypto.appendChild(p2);
  divCrypto.appendChild(p3);
  }
console.log(data);
};

getData();
console.log(data);
```

I tried with : setInterval (getData, 1000); but after each second, it recreates the HTML elements again and again.

I also tried to make 2 different functions but I don't know how to access the data outside the getData() function.

If I console log it outside, after the function is called and the data is updated, I get [] and I cannot understand why.

Comment: you can just empty the element and append to it, so before you append to divCrypto just add a `divCrypto.innerHTML = '';`

Comment: Is not working.  I tried and it only creates one single element although the function is looped 3 times.

Comment: Ah, i see, you need 3 results in there, then add that before the loop, and also if you need 3 results your for loop needs to be `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)`

Comment: Test it here: https://codepen.io/wyzix33/pen/xxLbbdV?editors=1011

Comment: Yes, is working like this but it rewrites the HTML elements over and over.
I would like to just update the API data and update the elements.innerHTML. 
Isn't that possible?

Comment: It is, but for that you need to create the HTML first, get the elements in JS and update the values only, I'll try to create an example

Comment: Try it here : https://codepen.io/wyzix33/pen/xxLbbdV?editors=1011

Comment: I've added an extra getData() before the setInterval so it won't wait 1 second before the data is fetched, also you can style the elements as you like, just keep the ids

Comment: Thank you but is not helpful in my case. I loop through like 100-200 crypto coins. That's why I made the document.createElement. So that I won't manually write hundred of HTML code.

Comment: https://codepen.io/wyzix33/pen/xxLbbdV?editors=1011 See if this is what you need, you just need to add to the html object the coins you want to display and the function will generate the html for them if it doesn't exist or just update the values if they do exists

Comment: It looks like it's working fine! Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238026/discussion-between-damian-and-gabriel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to the html object the coins you want to display and the function will generate the html for them if it doesn't exist or just update the values if they do exists

```js
let divCrypto = document.getElementById("divCrypto");
let html = { BTC: 1, ETH: 1, ADA: 1 };
let data = [];
let temp, p1, p2, p3, container;
const getData = async () => {
  coinName = await fetch("https://api.coinlore.net/api/tickers/").then((res) =>
    res.json()
  );
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    data.push(coinName.data[i]);
    container = document.getElementById(data[i].symbol);
    if (html[data[i].symbol] && !container) {
      // if this is the first time we read this coin we generate the html
      container = document.createElement("div");
      container.id = data[i].symbol;
      p1 = document.createElement("p");
      p2 = document.createElement("p");
      p3 = document.createElement("p");
      container.appendChild(p1);
      container.appendChild(p2);
      container.appendChild(p3);
      divCrypto.appendChild(container);
    }
    if (html[data[i].symbol]) {
      container.children[0].innerHTML = "Coin:" + " " + data[i].name;
      container.children[1].innerHTML = "Coin:" + " " + data[i].price_usd;
      container.children[2].innerHTML = data[i].percent_change_7d + "%";
    }
  }
  console.log(data);
};
getData();
setInterval(getData, 1000);
//console.log(data);
```

```html
<div id="divCrypto"></div>
```